# {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: s"}

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to create a stand alone program using a sqlite database but it keeps showing the following error every time I insert. I checked my  parameters and none of them are null. Here is my insert code.

```
public bool insertToTable(SQLiteConnection sql,string TableName, string Date, string Receipt, string Particulars, string Description, string Category, double amount)
{
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql);
    if (sql == null)
        return false;
    string statement = 
        "INSERT INTO @table (Date, Receipt,Particulars,Description,Category,Amount) " +
        "VALUES (@date, @rec,@part,@desc,@cat,@amt)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",Date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rec", Receipt);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@part", Particulars);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Description);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", Category);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amt", amount);
    command.Prepare();
    int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return true;
}
```

and the stack trace is

```
 at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.ToUTF8(String sourceText)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ConnectToDb.sqlitecommand.insertToTable(SQLiteConnection sql, String TableName, String Date, String Receipt, String Particulars, String Description, String Category, Double amount) in C:\Users\Jon Stephen\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConnectToDb\ConnectToDb\sqlitecommand.cs:line 45
   at ConnectToDb.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Jon Stephen\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConnectToDb\ConnectToDb\Form1.cs:line 36
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: What is the value for `@table` where you are assigning this?

Comment: this is my code snippet for the insert. my table value is tester. sqlitecommander.insertToTable(dbConnection, "tester", "4/1", "rec", "part", "desc", "cat", 3.3);

Comment: You can't parameterize identifires. `Insert into @Table...` should generate an exception even if you will add `@table` as a parameter to the command.

Answer (score 0):

First sight: The table name for SQL statement should be given from method parameter instead of SQL parameter. Your code should looks like this:

```
public boolean insertToTable (SQLiteConnection sql, string TableName, string Date, string Receipt, string Particulars, string Description, string Category, double amount)
{
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql);
    if (sql == null)
        return false;
    String statement = 
        "INSERT INTO " + TableName + " (Date, Receipt,Particulars,Description,Category,Amount) " +
        "VALUES (@date, @rec,@part,@desc,@cat,@amt)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",Date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rec", Receipt);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@part", Particulars);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Description);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", Category);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amt", amount);
    command.Prepare();
    int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // change to command.ExecuteNonQuery() depending what you need
    return true;
}
```

and while executed:

```
sqlitecommander.insertToTable(dbConnection, "tester", "4/1", "rec", "part", "desc", "cat", 3.3);
```

will produce SQL statement as this:

```
INSERT INTO tester (Date,Receipt,Particulars,Description,Category,Amount) VALUES ('4/1', 'rec', 'part', 'desc', 'cat', 3.3)
```

The exception occurred since you didn't provide any table name to insert into DB (proving that `@table` is null or empty), CMIIW.

Comment: thank you for the reply sir, but it still produces the same error. Do you think it has something to do with the creation of the table?

Comment: public string createTable() {
            return        @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [tester] (
                          [Date] VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                          [Receipt] VARCHAR(2048)  NULL,
                          [Particulars] VARCHAR(2048) NULL,
                          [Description] VARCHAR(2048)  NULL,
                          [Category] VARCHAR(2048)  NULL,
                          [Amount] VARCHAR(2048) NULL   
                          )"; }

Comment: I see your Amount column data type is `VARCHAR`, you should provide apostrophe for its value when inserting, i.e. '3.3' or use `FLOAT` data type. if you need to convert amount as string, provide `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amt", amount.ToString());`

Comment: oh yeah sry didnt see that.

Comment: it still does the same error. even after i changed it.

Comment: Since the question only provided error stack trace, it's difficult to determine what message contained in the error as problem's clue. Check your SQLiteConnection connection string first, then make sure your insert query executed properly on SQLite before running the app.

Answer (score 0):

It was a compatibility issue with my sqlite version, I downloaded a 32bit sqlite rather than a 64 bit.I downloaded the 64 bit through Nuget then that solved the problem.